# category__and works, but why?

Tags: categories, wp-query

I've already found a solution for my question/query but I can't help feeling dirty; this works, but I don't know why, or if there is a better solution.

I have a post that has several categories, for example:

> Cat ID: 6,358,23,402

From these categories, 358 (one specific publication) and 402 (another specific publication) are sub-categories of 11 (publication parent). The other two (6,23) I'm not interested in.

My loop:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $args = array(
            'category__and' => array( $category->cat_ID , 11 )
            'order'         => 'DESC',              // List in ascending order
            'orderby'       => 'id',                // List them in their menu order
            'showposts'     => 1
        );
        $publicationPosts = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($publicationPosts->have_posts()) : $publicationPosts->the_post(); ?>         
            <div class="module-publication-single">
                //content
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

What `category__and` should do is compare every category ID with 11 (my publication parent ID):

- 6   => 11
- 358 => 11
- 23  => 11
- 402 => 11

and decide if there is something to do or not. For 358 and 402, as they are sons of 11, it shows the content, but for 6 and 23 it shows nothing. That's exactly what I want, but I don't know why; is it an inheritance situation?

Comment: There is obviously a language barrier, which is OK, but I can't understand quite what your question/goal is. Do you want only children of 11 that are assigned to a particular post?

Comment: Hi, @s-ha-dum, thanks for answering. Yes, I tried to be as clear as I could, but it wasn't enough.
Categories 358 and 402 are children of 11. Category 6 and 23 are not. 
This loop shows exactly what I want but It doesn't look fine for me. category__and works only for comparing categories with their children?

Comment: So none of resulting posts have `11` actually assigned? Why would you _want_ to query posts with `11` then?

Comment: No, the posts don't have a 11 category assigned, they have children categories of 11. The thing is that I don't know all 11's children, they continue to grow. So, I need to show all the publications associated to my post:
For exemple, here, 
http://www.galerieflak.com/tomahawk-upper-missouri/
I need to show all the publications at bottom left : Indiens(cat => 358) and Pas 2014 (cat => 402)